# How do I add the same contacts to multiple mailing lists in Contacts.app?

Tags: email, contacts.app, group

I use the "Send email to [name of group]" option in Mac Contacts. It's fast , efficient, and organized.

I have run into a problem when I add a contact to Contacts group. Instead of adding a reference to a new list, the software actually removes the contact from any other group that it is in and adds it to the new group. In effect, it "moves" rather than "copies" or makes a reference.

**I need to build multiple mailing lists (groups) and some people I'm mailing to need to be on different lists for different reasons.**

**Is this possible?**

Contacts is Version 2536, on Ventura 13.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have discovered the problem. It's not tested, but it's an educated assumption.

The lists that I created are on a computer at a work location I am contracting at. This company—against all good advice—uses a Microsoft Exchange server. Per the [Apple support webpage](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/contacts/adrb3280fe91/mac#adrb9e3b3974):

> If you use an Exchange account in Contacts, those contacts can belong
> to only one folder at a time. Any contacts that aren’t in a folder you
> create are in the default Exchange Contacts folder.

This explains the behaviour that I did not expect.

Oh well. I will work around this issue. It makes one weep for those poor benighted fools who cling to the dark ages of computing.

Comment: The most efficient workaround I came up with was to manually add the same note to each (of around 50) contacts. This was just something simple but unique, like "Accounting Distribution list 2023". Then I created a smart list with all cards that contained "Accounting Distribution list 2023" in the notes section. For people who cross several lists, the note chains like so: "Accounting Distribution list 2023, Active Mentorship Programme, Company Cookbook Author" and each smart list refers to one of these substrings within the note. It's a bit of a plodge, but it works so far.